# GLKView snapshot returns distorted image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimage, glkview

I am using [CIFunHouse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013431) apple demo for my project to applying filter effects, When I try to take a snapshot of GLKView on iPad Air by making

```
 UIImage* imageCaptured = [(GLKView*)_videoPreviewView snapshot];
```

the UIImage generated have distortion. see image
[image]

Any ideas? How to fix this.
Thanks in advance.